# Does the fastlane CLI provide an option to specify the location of a fastfile?

Tags: fastlane

I would like to run fastlane from the command line of the parent directory of my project. Is it possible to specify the location of the directory that fastlane will work out of?

something like: `fastlane --path=./project/ lint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option currently.
The only way you could achieve this, is by changing the current directory to the one where the fastlane configuration is preset.

```
cd ./project/
fastlane lint
```